# Разбить предложение на массив

Tags: c#, массивы

Возник второй и последний на сегодня вопрос. Как можно разбить предложение, к примеру, "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю" на массив. По гуглив прочитал, что можно через Split. Но найти, как правильно применять, так и не смог.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить разделение на массив.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Открыл ссылку на [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx). Там мало того, что уже на русском расписано, да ещё и пример прямо под Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

В принципе, можно использовать только обычный Split и разбивать по пробелам. Но результат может получиться несколько "грязным" - помимо пробелов слова разделяются также знаками препинания. 
К примеру, предложение "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю"  разобьется на такой массив:

"Съешь", "ещё", "этих", "мягких", "французских", **"булок,"**, "да", "выпей", "чаю"

тогда как ожидалось, вероятно, такое:

"Съешь", "ещё", "этих", "мягких", "французских", **"булок"**, "да", "выпей", "чаю"

Поэтому нужно будет использовать еще немного LINQ. Например, так:

```
const string pattern = "Съешь ещё этих: мягких французских булок, да! выпей чаю";
var delimiters = new[] { ".", ",", "\'", "\"", ":", ";", "!", "?" };                        var res = delimiters.Aggregate(pattern, (current, delimiter) =>   current.Replace(delimiter, "")).Split(new [] { ' ' });
```

В этом варианте знаки препинания будут отфильтрованы

Comment: мне на буквы нужно.

Comment: @Vlmake string s = "dsdsd";

s.ToCharArray() - массив чаров копируется

s.Chars - массив чаров в строке

Comment: >мне на буквы нужно

тогда стоило сформулировать вопрос более корректно. как известно, телепатов тут нет

Comment: @DreamChild, что-то я не очень понимаю. Чем вам такой вариант не угодил?

`pattern.Split(new[]{'.', ',', '\'', '\"', ':', ';', '!', '?', ' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Раз пошла такая пьянка, внесу еще один способ :D

    string[] res = Regex.Matches(str, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

Упустил из виду, что делить нужно на буквы... Соответственно вместо w+ нужно использовать просто w

Comment: @IsM, в таком случае удобнее будет `Regex.Split(str, @"\W+")`, только потом лучше посмотреть первый и последний элемент массива - там могут быть пустые строки.

Для разбиения на символы, как уже было сказано, есть `ToCharArray()`.